# Recreate squarespace aimation with pngs

Tags: css, html, animation, png

Does anybody know hoy to recreate the animation on the right of  the screen?
How is it done?
http://www.squarespace.com/

I am trying to recreate that effect on my website, where a hand scrolls over an ipad.

Thanks!
Damian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have created a very large image with each frame of the animation positioned beside the next, horizontally.

http://cf.squarespace.com/details/musician-hand-sequence-hires.png

The image is set as the background image of a element, which is sized to the same size as one frame of the animation. Then, the `background-position` is changed to control which frame of the animation is shown, probably through javascript.